# How to build ARIMA model from my time series?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, model-selection, autocorrelation

I have created couple of graphs in R

```
d5 <- scan('d500.txt')
p1 <- acf(d5,lag.max = 36 ,type = c("covariance"),plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

Then the next one is correlation

```
p1 <- acf(d5,lag.max = 36 ,type = c("correlation"),plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

And pacf

```
p1 <- pacf(d5,lag.max = 36 ,plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

If I take a one difference operation

```
d51 <- diff(d5)
p1 <- acf(d51,lag.max = 36 ,type = c("correlation"),plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

And then again acf
[image]

and pacf

[image]

How to interpret this?What does sinusoidal acf(cov) shows?
Original data set is here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8cmv02xtyvyrilp/d500.txt?dl=0

Comment: Acf's , pacf's etc reflect  descriptive symptoms . Causes are found by analytics . Please post the original data so I can (maybe) unravel thus conundrum .

Comment: also please advise what kind of data is this .. frequency of measurements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You originally had 500,000 readings, 128 per second for 3,907 seconds. After taking the readings at 1 second interval (N=3907) the plot is here [image] . AUTOBOX identified a break point in parameters at period 2343 +/- 300 time points. Taking the most recent 1565 values this is then the identified model [image]  (1,1,0) with an ACF of the residuals here suggesting model insufficiency [image]. It appears that there is significant auto-projective structure at period 60 suggesting an hourly effect .There were a few (8) anomalous data points ( also visually obvious) which were identified and rectified/adjusted . Some sort of SARIMA might be necessary of the form (1,1,0)(1,0,0)60 . I will sharpen my pencil and try to resolve this as ARIMA modelling is an ITERATIVE PROCESS.

AFTER ADDING A 60 PERIOD COEFFICIENT :

[image]

this captures the short-term (second) and the long-term (hourly) structure