# How do you deal with time series with long seasonality period?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, seasonality

I have a few time series (20+) to be jointly forecasted. They are minute-level data with an obvious weekly seasonality. Therefore the seasonality is 7*24*60=10080.

Typical time series model can not handle such a long seasonality, since it requires a huge number of seasonality parameters (I tried DLM and some similar models).

Most time series models require deseasonality before feeding, is there any way to deal with this long seasonality?

Comment: [Here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) is Rob J. Hyndman's blog post specifically on this topic. Search also for related threads on Cross Validated, something like [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=long+seasonal+period).

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy! That's definitely a good start point.

Comment: I'd be thinking about looking at trigonometric seasonality not dummy seasonality. You can probably get an adequate fit with only a few components. Do you seem to have stationarity across weeks?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes a fourier series seems to be able to capture the seasonality pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider possibly using deterministic structure such as 6 dummies for day-of-the-week , 23 dummies for hour-of-the-day and arma structure for short term memory. [How to build ARIMA model from my time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253376/how-to-build-arima-model-from-my-time-series/253431#253431) might be of interest